# Merge this data into one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I am trying to figure out if I can get rid of tables.

Right now I have tasks and appointments. Both these tables have different columns and store different information so I can't and won't combine these tables.

However for each task and appointment you can set multiple reminders(sent through sms, email and both).

Now right now I have 2 separate reminders tables. They both have the same columns expect for the FKs.

[image]

So is it possible to use the same table for both?

The only way I see that happening is that I always have both FK in the table but one is always null(this seems wrong).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
Reminder
  - ID
  - ReminderDate
  - EntityID     -- Could be TaskID or AppointmentID
  - EntityType   -- TASK or APPOINTMENT
```

### Insertion

```
INSERT INTO Reminder(@ReminderID, @TaskID, 'TASK') 
INSERT INTO Reminder(@ReminderID, @AppointmentID, 'APPOINTMENT')
```

### Selection

```
SELECT * FROM Reminder WHERE EntityID=@TaskID AND EntityType='TASK' -- Reminders for Task

SELECT * FROM Reminder WHERE EntityID=@AppointmentID AND EntityType='Appointment' -- Reminders for Appointment
```

Comment: also create a composite index on (EntityType, EntityID). set it unique if every entity can have only 1 appointment.

Comment: Hey, I should have mentioned in my OP but I am using nhibernate, how will this work with nhibernate? Since usually you map it to an object which in this case it could be 2 different objects.

Answer (score 0):

"The only way I see that happening is that I always have both FK in the table but one is always null(this seems wrong)."

I don't see anything wrong with it. It is your business rule. You can enforce it at the database level with check constraint (2 foreign keys + check constraint that always one field must be not null and other one null).

Anyway it is better IMO to retain this solution and have proper foreign keys than use EntityID, EntityType trick IMO.

Use database features to enforce data integrity. Otherwise the probability to get bad data goes up. You can enforce some rules in your code but probability that you will make an error or enforce your business rule is much higher than using DB features like foreign key constraint.

Comment: So are you saying that you would use 2 tables or you would use one table but have fk's nullable

Comment: I'm saying that the approach with one table with 2 FKs doesn't seem wrong to me. And the approach @codingbiz suggests doesn't use FKs and that seems wrong to me.

Comment: hmm. Still not sure what I will do might just leave it then as 2 tables.

Comment: The approach with 2 tables is also OK IMO. Pick one and go on. You can always refactor later.